# PostGIS raster connection is not closed by MapServer

Tags: postgis, raster, mapserver

I'm using PostGIS raster in MapServer like this:

```
TYPE RASTER
DATA "PG:port=6432 dbname='mydb' user='postgres' password='1234' schema='public' table='truemarble' mode='2'"
PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=ALWAYS"
```

My problem is that the database connection is not closed after a request. The PROCESSING directive should ensure the disconnection and this works fine with PostGIS vectors.

Any ideas?

I've tested with:
python_mapscript in a mod_python application
php_mapscript in a php-fpm application (Fastcgi)

MapServer 6.2 and 6.4, GDAL 1.10, Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04